# Cannot enter password automatically in Terminal PuTTY plink command to connect CentOS 7 in Windows

Tags: ssh, putty, plink, windows-terminal

I want to connect CentOS 7 in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), when I use command:

```
ssh root@192.168.50.160
```

The arrow keys works well, but `ssh` command can't enter password automatically.

So, I use PuTTY `plink` command like this:

```
plink -ssh 192.168.50.160 -l root -pw password
```

But the arrow keys are not working.

How to fix this? Or is there another way to connect to Linux can enter password automatically in Windows Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY Plink is not intended for an interactive use, see [its documentation](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html):

> It is mostly *used for automated operations*, such as making CVS access a repository on a remote server.
>
> Plink is probably *not what you want if you want to run an interactive session* in a console window.

---

Use `ssh` with a public key authentication instead of the password authentication, if you do not want to type the password.